# Why Firebase Remote Config still return old value even if the conditions aren't met

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm working on an app that, when launched, ask to Remote Config if there is an app update available.

To achieve that, on Firebase I've set a key `update` with two conditions, the platform must be Android and the app version must be included in the list, example: `1.0.0`,  `1.0.1`, `1.1.0`, `etc..`.

If this condition is `true` it will return **update_required** otherwise it return **none**.

When the app is launched i call the `fetchAndActivate` method like that:

```
remoteConfig = Firebase.remoteConfig

val configSettings = remoteConfigSettings {
    minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds = 10800
    fetchTimeoutInSeconds = 30
}
remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)
remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->        
        checkUpdateAvailable()
    }
```

The `checkUpdateAvailable()` method does this:

```
private fun checkUpdateAvailable() {
    if (remoteConfig.getString("update").contains("update_required")) {
        ...update app...
    } else {
        ...login...
    }
}
```

Basically it start the update flow.

The problem though is that after i've correctly updated and relaunched my app to the new version, that should not return **update_required**, it still return **update_required** when `remoteConfig.getString("update")` method is called.

The only thing that seems to work is to force Firebase to download the new Remote Configs by setting `minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds = 0`.

To my knowledge, when Firebase fetch the remote configs it download all the key/value structure and not only the single value.

Having that said i can't understand why i still receive the old value, it seems that Firebase ignore the conditions and return the last value that has returned, until a new fetch will happen.

In iOS the same app work with no problem, with the same configuration and the same logics.

Is there something that i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below one line after initialise Firebase Remote Config

> mFirebaseRemoteConfig.reset();

Every time, it will give you updated value